# How can I make items of two JavaScript arrays correspond to each other?

Tags: javascript

Delving into arrays today with javascript. I have created two arrays

```
    var items = ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Butter']
    var calories = [10,20,30]
```

The idea is that the calories correspond to the item, so bread has 10 calories. And if I want to see the two arrays combining results then i call this

```
   document.writeln(items[1] +  calories[1])
```

I'm guessing theres a much more efficient way of doing this, but as a newbie I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Ideally I want to store all the info in one array

Comment: Great page for this - about half way down: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: @RayK: please [don't link to w3schools](http://w3fools.com) - It's not a great resource, [MDN offers better documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who has answered, big help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way would be to use an object instead of an array:

```
var items = {
   Bread: 10, 
   Milk: 20, 
   Butter: 30
};

alert(items["Bread"]); // Alert 10
```

There is [a good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on MDN about working with objects in JavaScript that might be useful to you.

Comment: Rather than `alert()` I'd suggest: [using `console.log()`, a `for (x in object)` and an `if (object.hasOwnProperty(x))` approach](http://jsfiddle.net/cF5Cw/). Otherwise, yes. =)

Comment: @DavidThomas Sure, I couldn't agree more. Just wanted to keep the example as clear and simple as possible. Good reference though!

Answer (score 4):

You could use an array of objects:

```
var items = [
   {Bread: 10},
   {Milk:20}
];
```

or simply an object

```
var items {
    Bread:10,
    Milk:20
}
```

To print the breads calories using a Key-Value approach:

```
   alert(items["Bread"]);
```

If you dont want to use the itemname as the "key", you can do this:

```
var items = [
   {
    Item: "Bread", 
    Calories: 10
   },
   {
    Item: "Milk", 
    Calories: 20
   }
];
```

Then you can print it like so:

```
alert(items[0].Item+" has "+items[0].Calories+" calories");
```

Then, if you wish to add elements:

```
items.push({Item:"Butter",Calories:30});
```

Comment: Right, haven't had my coffee yet. :)

Comment: Seems as if Im using the wrong tool for the job then, object rather than array for this particular example

Comment: Advantage of the first version is that it can keep the order, and accommodate more fields.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you mean by "more efficent" really but something like this is more like you want to model:

```
var items = {
  'Bread': 10,
  'Milk': 20,
  'Butter': 30
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about hashtables/dictionaries?

```
var calories = { Bread: 10,  Milk: 20, Butter: 30 };
```

To get the desired output from this object, check my (Elias Van Ootegem) answer.
or "objects":

```
var food = [ 
     { name: 'Bread', calories: 10 },
     { name: 'Milk', calories: 20 },
     { name: 'Butter', calories: 30 },
];
```

To get the output here:

```
for (var i=0;i<food.length;i++)
{
    document.writeln(food[i].name +': '+food[i].calories);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for an object literal. You want your output to be something like this:

```
var items = {
    Bread: 10,
    Milk : 20
};
```

You can loop through the array and fill an initially empty array, like this:

```
var items = {}, food, calories;

food = ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Butter'];
calories = [10,20,30];

for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < calories.length; l++) {
        items[ food[i] ] = calories[ l ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so like everybody tells you, an object is what you need. To get to the actual output:

```
var items = {
   'Bread' : 10, 
   'Milk', : 20, 
   'Butter' : 30
};
for (var name in items)
{//loop through object literal, list all properties
    if (items.hasOwnProperty(name))
    {//avoid output of prototype properties
        document.writeln(name + ': ' + items[name]);
    }
}
//output:
    Bread: 10
    Milk: 20
    Butter: 30
```